# Help with MathDesign fonts, namely URW-Garamond

Tags: fonts, mathdesign

I really want to use `urw-garamond` with the `mathdesign` package, but for some reason `pdflatex` is throwing errors anytime I try and use it.
I've installed the `mathdesign` package with the TeX Live Utility and I'm using pdflatex with BasicTeX.

[Here's what I'm trying to do.](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/dCTRtIxwVM3U78Cl6Xoq/)

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you know if you actually have the URW Garamond font files installed? Those fonts do not use a completely free/open source license, and so are often not distributed with TeXlive or installable through its package manager (even if the mathdesign.sty file is).

On linux you can install them using [the getnonfreefonts script](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) -- I suspect that might work for BasicTeX too (on a mac?), but I don't have first hand experience of that.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the file texnansi.enc is missing. There exists certainly a texlive package which contains this file. A google search suggests "ly1" and "texlive-fonts-extra".

Comment: (Originally a comment by an anonymous user) The ly1 package from texlive solved it for me!!