# Getting URW-Garamond and the license

Tags: fonts, licensing

I want to use URW-garamond but it seems although [this source](http://ftp.fagskolen.gjovik.no/pub/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/MD-urw-garamond-doc.pdf) claims I probably should have it I do not. Furthermore [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7023/help-with-mathdesign-fonts-namely-urw-garamond) on this site indicates that I in fact should not at all expect to have it on my system. So now I want to know two things:

1. What in it's license makes it unsuitable for inclusion in LaTeX distributions and
2. Given that I actually can get it how would I go about installing it on different distributions? (I use tex-live on Ubuntu and Mac and TeXworks on Windows but please list all distributions you can think of)

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond says that the fonts are free for private use, but not for commercial use. You can download the fonts from the same location.

Comment: And if you want to buy the commercial fonts from e.g. http://www.urw.de, using them with XeTeX or LuaTeX will be easy.

Comment: Note also that EB Garamond is another great, open-source Garamond font, which you can use with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond doesn't have real small caps. Having them is a must (IMHO). I've used _Adobe Garamond Premiere Pro_ with XeLaTeX and with pdflatex. The first works out of the box but XeLaTeX isn't fully compatible with `microtype` yet. The second route requires `otftotfm` and this worked fine. I've described the implementation details of the ```otftotfm`'' route in [LaTeX and Friend](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) but for a different typeface: _Nexus_.

Comment: @IRaphink Nice information. Didn't know about that.

Comment: You could have a look at [this repository of TeX software by M. Sharpe](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3825336/TeX/index.html) and search for all the entries related to Garamond.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. It has a [**nosell** license](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/licenses.nosell.html), and there are all types of licenses - [The TeX Catalogue License Definitions](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/licenses.html). TeX distributions usually include only packages that fall in the category of **Free software**.
2. There is no problem, you can install it wherever you want.

---

Installation instructions:

1. Get all `.afm` and `.pfb` files from here - [**urw-garamond**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond).
2. Copy all `.afm` files to `<root>/fonts/afm/urw/garamond`, and all `.pfb` files to `<root>/fonts/type1/urw/garamond`, creating any missing folders in these paths. Where `<root>` is your *local* (recommended) or *global TeX tree*. In *Linux* local tree is called usually `localtexmf`, respectively `texmf` for the global tree. In *Windows*, MiKTeX has a default global tree as, for example `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` (Windows XP, MiKTeX 2.9). There is no default local tree created. You can create one via the *Settings* GUI.
3. In Linux issue the command `texhash` as root. In Windows, for MiKTeX issue the command `initexmf --update-fndb`. Or via the *Settings* GUI press the button *Refresh FNDB*.
4. If not installed, install the package [**mathdesign**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/) via the respective package manager. It's available in both TeXLive and MiKTeX.
5. In preamble add `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}` to use it.

**Edit:** Added installation instructions.

**Edit:** Fixed a typo: `initexmf --update-fnbd` -> `initexmf --update-fndb`

Comment: I was hoping for instructions on the actual installation process...

Comment: Added installation instructions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a script `getnonfreefonts` available that makes it easy to install a number of fonts including URW-Garamond.  The directions are found at http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/.  On my Ubuntu system with TeX Live, I was simply able to run the following in the terminal to download and install the script:

```
# download installation file and install script
wget https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts

# optional: clean up the installation file
rm install-getnonfreefonts
```

This installed the script `getnonfreefonts` to `/usr/local/bin` and the corresponding documentation to `/usr/local/share/man`.  On my system the shell looks for executables and documentation in these two locations so I was simply able to run the following:

```
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

Running `getnonfreefonts --sys -a` downloaded all of the available fonts (of which URW_Garamond is one) and put them in the appropriate directories in my texmf tree.  This took about a minute.  After that, the downloaded fonts worked using the appropriate `\usepackage` directives!

---

Edit: as per a comment, use `getnonfreefonts-sys` rather than `getnonfreefonts` (edited above).  See [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) for why.

---

Edit 2: it seems that for newer versions of `getnonfreefonts` there is no executable `getnonfreefonts-sys` and you should use the `--sys` option for `getnonfreefonts` instead.

Comment: But see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255709