# How to ensure that Droid Sans and Garamond are available on the system

Tags: fonts

I’m writing a class file and wish to use Droid Sans and Garamond which is no problem width `\usepackage{droidsans}` and `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`. With my TeX Live 2012 on Mac OS X eveything works like a charm but the client, I’m writing the class for, uses Windows XP, Suse and Ubuntu where TeX can’t find all necessary font files, although `droidsans` and `mathdesign` are available.

The question is what do I have to do to make the font available for any user (with an up to date distribution)? I guess there’s nothing I can do directly but I would like to explain in the manual what to do to install the fonts …

### Update

Heres a small example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% simulate class option
\newif\iffonts% to prevent the class
                % loading any font packages
\fontstrue

\iffonts
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{droidsans}
   \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\fi

\begin{document}
\chapter{Section one}
Some text
\end{document}
```

This should be compiled with `pdflatex`. It qould be great if there’d be a solution for WIndows and Ubuntu (other users can help themselves or use `\fontsfalse`). One may also use `\fontsfalse` when using any other machin then `pdflatex`. The font support must only work with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user has to install the packages [`mathdesign`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign), [`droidsans`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/droid) and [`urw-garamond`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond). The best would be to install the packages with the package manager of the used `tex` distribution. If not possible he has to follow the installation instructions in the readme files. It would be the best to install the font urw-garamond in a local texmf tree. More hints you can find in question [getting-urw-garamond-and-the-license](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19898/getting-urw-garamond-and-the-license).

With some changes your MWE should then compile:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% simulate class option
\newif\iffonts% to prevent the class
                % loading any font packages
\fontstrue

\iffonts
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ugm}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{droidsans}
  \usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\fi


\begin{document}
\chapter{Section one}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do I need to change `\rmdefault` manually, doesn’t `mathdesign` do it? With TeX Live on Mac OSX it’s obviously not necessary …

Comment: I tried the instruction from the linked question and it works fine for Ubuntu with TEX Live 2012 but not on Win 7 with MikTeX (Error: `Trying to make PK font md-gmro8y at 657 DPI... Running miktex-makemf.exe... | miktex-makemf: The md-gmro8y source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe... | miktex-makepk: PK font md-gmro8y could not be created.`)

Comment: I installed a fresh MikTeX a few days ago, so I guess it’s the current version. My first try was to install only the files listet in the linked answer. Then I added the other files. I ran the FNDB update after each try without success. DO you have an idea, why it works an Ubuntu and if I do the same in Win it doesn’t – are MikTeX and TeX Live too different in this case?

Comment: OK … I did it again as explained in the readme file and Garamond works. But droidsans not yet (Error: |miktex-makepk: PK font DroidSans-01 could not be created.|) …

Comment: Update: I found http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2165/ and it made Droid Sans work but only the normal and italic faces work the bold face doesn’t :-( any ideas?

Comment: Hm … thats why I stick to TL :-) I guess the way to go is accept the missing bold face or use TL. Thanks for you help!